# Help my ugly Latex Table

Tags: tables, overleaf

I'm trying to make it look a professional, or at least better from all the vertical lines. tables in LaTeX, as they tend to be pretty ugly and hard to maintain most of the time. Almost all examples/how-tos about tables produce results which are kind of embarrassing,

would anyone here expert to add some touches to my table please

```
% Initialising the document type with some formatting information
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{article}

% Allow urls to be split at end of line
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
% Allow tables to be read in from CSV and use centered width formatted columns
\usepackage{csvsimple,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}

% Allow tables and figures to be referenced by name
% https:,,tex.stackexchange.com,questions,397031,conflict-with-hyperref-and-titlesec
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Allow long things to be split
\usepackage{seqsplit}

% Remove the indentation when starting new paragraphs, but still add a blank line.
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

% Allow multiple line comments.
\usepackage{verbatim}

% Package for dealing with graphics - for figures.
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Allows a space to be included after inserting formatted text.
\usepackage{xspace}

% add line numbers
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

%% Allow more control over chapters and sections etc.
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%
%% Allow the paragraph tag to mark extra section depth  
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
%\titleformat{\paragraph}
%{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
%\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

% Allow single pages to be changed to landscape, including in PDF preview.
\usepackage{lscape}

% Allow figures to be rotated and included in landscape.
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

% Allow wrapping for landscape pages
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Allow columns to span multiple rows.
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

% More formatting options for lists
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Allow different colouring for individual cells in tables.
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Allow more complex formatting of tables.
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Special centred and auto-widthed table
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

% Allow page spanning tables
\usepackage{longtable}

% Allow tables to be forced into position with [H]. - don't remember what this meant
% plaintiff should force caption to top
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

% Parnotes package organises footnotes in tables
\usepackage[roman]{parnotes}
\makeatletter
\def\parnoteclear{%
    \gdef\PN@text{}%
    \parnotereset
} 

% To allow ticks in tables (by typing \tick)
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\tick}{\ding{52}}

% Package to allow some maths stuff (±)
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Set the margin widths
\usepackage[top=2.45cm,bottom=2.45cm,left=3.17cm,right=3.17cm,twoside]{geometry}

% Allow figures and tables to be named in different ways.
\usepackage{chngcntr}
% Count tables individually within each section.
%\counterwithin{table}{section}
%\counterwithin{figure}{section}

% Allow Harvard formatting for references - reference with \citep{key,key2,etc.}. Or \citept{key} to reference as Name et al. (2012)
% Remember that you have to run Macros -> Applescript -> Bibliography (?r) to make references appear
% The style file for this is referred to in the section at the bottom.
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

% First line adds the reference section to the Contents page, second line renames it from 'Bibliography' to 'References'
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\settocbibname{References}

% This package allows a list of abbreviations to be created (make sure it is added to the contents - "intoc").
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

% double quotation
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Format the document with double line spacing. - should this be 1.655 or 2
%\linespread{1.7}
% Allow the gap around captions to be increased to aid legibility on tables
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[figure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
% Below is probably preferable - turns off double line spacing for figure legends and within tables (makes all tables much smaller)
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\onehalfspacing

% Allow text to be placed at the bottom of a page
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}

% Allow double spacing in tables - usually reverted to single by setspace
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\doublespacing}

\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
\usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
\fontsize{12}{20}%
\selectfont}

\begin{document}


    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[]
        \centering

        \caption{Summary of transposable elements }
        \label{tab:Table1}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.8\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|cc|ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
        \hline

        Class & Order & \multicolumn{3}{c}{rom }  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{act} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{erus} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cos} \\
         &  & Numbers & Length (bp) & \%  & Numbers & Length (bp) & \% & Numbers & Length (bp) & \% & Numbers & Length (bp) & \% \\
         \hline
          \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Class I\\ \end{tabular} &  &  &   &   &  &  &   &  &  &  &  &   &   \\
         \hline

         &SINEs:               & 255687    & 30551159 & 1.52            & 257887  & 31080491  & 1.56             & 261248   &  31533761  & 1.57                    & 258371           & 30783770    &1.42 \\
         &Alu/B1               & 0 & 0     & 0.00                       & 0  & 0   & 0.00                        & 0       & 0      & 0.00                                       & 0       &0    & 0.00  \\
         &MIRs                 & 247894 & 30250569     & 1.51           & 249065  & 30760408   & 1.54            & 251376   & 31188301      & 1.55                 & 248923       &30437726    &1.40  \\
         &LINEs:               & 498627 & 207732214   & 10.37           & 501561  & 211005106  & 10.59           &516019  &220321176   &10.97                      & 543212      &226312996    &10.42  \\
         &LINE1               & 338909 & 163725095   & 8.17             & 342054  & 166954821   & 8.38           &354388  &175466399   &8.73                       &382755      &182566388     &8.40  \\
         &LINE2               & 133681  & 37311794    & 1.86            & 133693  & 37430629   &1.88             &135350   &38013575    &1.89                      &134657      &37312366      &1.72 \\
         &L3/CR1              & 16230   &3946140     & 0.20             & 16295   & 3952685  &0.20               &16386    &3999393     &0.20                      &16301         &3896521     &0.18 \\
         &RTE                 & 8327   & 2349410      & 0.12            & 8280   & 2342043   & 0.12              &8320    &2362314     &0.12                       &8391        &2315634     &0.11 \\

         \hline  
         &LTR elements:        & 2368202 & 360743057   & 18.00         &2138613 & 331038087   & 16.61           &2043931   &305371407   &15.20                     &2399880      &376465663   &17.33 \\
         \hline
         &ERVL                 & 603471 & 94653879   & 4.72            & 535533 & 89635873  &4.50               &457960   &74681407   &3.72                        &589003      &95266242     &4.39 \\
         &ERVL-MaLRs            & 936686 & 137736037  & 6.87           & 757066 & 122605363  &6.15              &683557   &105114613   &5.23                       &927914      &138867517    &6.39 \\
         &ERV\_classI            & 401868 & 69495491  &3.47            & 476978 &72572164  &3.64                &458525   &72184510   &3.59                        &442380      &80571827     & 3.71\\
         &ERV\_classII           & 179048 & 21382713  &1.07            & 143640 & 16451857  & 0.83              &146189     &18906035   &0.94                      &198036        &22430344   &1.03 \\
        \hline
        \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Class II\\

           \end{tabular} &  &  &   &      &  &   &   &  &  &  &  &   &  \\
            \hline
         & DNA transposons:    & 259000 &53746062  & 2.68             & 261351 & 54598424  & 2.74                     &264855  &55556571  &2.77                   & 265748      &54859043     &2.53 \\

         \hline
         & hAT-Charlie    &153463 & 28637685  & 1.43                 & 154577 & 29132748 & 1.46                      &156022  & 29603550  &1.47                   & 156955       &29239810    &1.35  \\
         & TcMar-Tigger    &36981 & 11185164  & 0.56                  & 38120 & 11441081 &0.57                      &39444   &11766559  &   0.59                  & 38989       &11514055   &0.53 \\

          \hline
         &Rolling-circles    & 659955 & 72981412  &3.64               & 803681 & 84486255 & 4.24                      &889437   &94191508  & 4.69                 & 738026       &79989304   &3.68 \\

          \hline
         &Unclassified.      & 3128 & 509710  & 0.03                 & 3147 & 512316 & 0.03                          &3191   &518292  & 0.03                     & 3167       &510872   &0.02  \\

            \hline 
        Total &              & 0 & 00000  & 000.25                & 0 &712929637  & 35.78                         & X & 00000 & 300
        \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \end{table}
        \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you include the necessary `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` so that we can copy, paste, and compile your example?  The general reference for better looking tables is the booktabs package and its documentation.  Have you looked through that?

Comment: `siunitx` might also come in handy in order to improve the alignment of numbers.

Comment: The part of the page that is available to the table changes from documentclass to documentclass. In order to give some useful advise on how to make your table look better, this information is important. Therefore please add it to your question. Settings to the `geometry` package also affect the output so please add them as well.

Comment: @Teepeemm I assume these two are included, kindly I'm new to latex, will you provide some references to read. but please if you are expert in this save my time and add some touches to it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i have the overleaf latex open on the other tap just tell me please how can i provide what you are asking

Comment: @leandriis please check the question, i hope i have provided what is missing

Comment: @Teepeemm check the question again

Comment: Don't you get an error message from this code complaining about `\cos` being used outside of math mode?

Comment: Regarding "look professional", "tables in LaTeX [...] tend to be pretty ugly", "produce results which are kind of embarrassing", "add some touches to my table": could you please clarify what your expected output looks like? "better"  might be quite subjective. Since you already mentioned vertical lines, why not start and remove them entirely?

Comment: @leandriis I have no idea what are you talking about, all my part in the project to report that table, the table looks fine all I'm trying here to improve it

Comment: I assume that you refer to the error message. Actually, your code results in such an error message that should be dealt with before touching the table to improve its look. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 5):

How about this? I removed all vertical lines, replaced some horizontal lines with a vertical spacing, reduced the fonntsize and the intercolumn spacing. Furthermore, the columns with numerical contents use the `S` columntype, from `siunitx` , to improve the legibility of the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Summary of transposable elements }
\label{tab:Table1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\,}r*{4}{S[table-format=7.0]@{\enspace}S[table-format=9.0]@{\enspace}S[table-format=2.2,table-number-alignment=center]}@{}}
\toprule
 \multirow{2.2}{*}{Class} & \multirow{2.2}{*}{Order\qquad}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{rom } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{act} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{erus} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$ \cos $} \\
 & & {Numbers} & {Length (bp)} & {\%} & {Numbers} & {Length (bp)} & \% & {Numbers} & {Length (bp)} & \% & {Numbers} & {Length (bp)} & \% \\
 \midrule\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Class I}} \\
 &SINEs: & 255687 & 30551159 & 1.52 & 257887 & 31080491 & 1.56 & 261248 & 31533761 & 1.57 & 258371 & 30783770 &1.42 \\
 &Alu/B1 & 0 & 0 & 0.00 & 0 & 0 & 0.00 & 0 & 0 & 0.00 & 0 &0 & 0.00 \\
 &MIRs & 247894 & 30250569 & 1.51 & 249065 & 30760408 & 1.54 & 251376 & 31188301 & 1.55 & 248923 &30437726 &1.40 \\
 &LINEs: & 498627 & 207732214 & 10.37 & 501561 & 211005106 & 10.59 &516019 &220321176 &10.97 & 543212 &226312996 &10.42 \\
 &LINE1 & 338909 & 163725095 & 8.17 & 342054 & 166954821 & 8.38 &354388 &175466399 &8.73 &382755 &182566388 &8.40 \\
 &LINE2 & 133681 & 37311794 & 1.86 & 133693 & 37430629 &1.88 &135350 &38013575 &1.89 &134657 &37312366 &1.72 \\
 &L3/CR1 & 16230 &3946140 & 0.20 & 16295 & 3952685 &0.20 &16386 &3999393 &0.20 &16301 &3896521 &0.18 \\
 &RTE & 8327 & 2349410 & 0.12 & 8280 & 2342043 & 0.12 &8320 &2362314 &0.12 &8391 &2315634 &0.11 \\
 \rowcolor{Gainsboro!40! Lavender}[4pt]& \llap{LTR elements:} & 2368202 & 360743057 & 18.00 &2138613 & 331038087 & 16.61 &2043931 &305371407 &15.20 &2399880 &376465663 &17.33 \\
 &ERVL & 603471 & 94653879 & 4.72 & 535533 & 89635873 &4.50 &457960 &74681407 &3.72 &589003 &95266242 &4.39 \\
 &\llap{ERVL-MaLRs} & 936686 & 137736037 & 6.87 & 757066 & 122605363 &6.15 &683557 &105114613 &5.23 &927914 &138867517 &6.39 \\
 &\llap{ERV\_classI} & 401868 & 69495491 &3.47 & 476978 &72572164 &3.64 &458525 &72184510 &3.59 &442380 &80571827 & 3.71\\
 &\llap{ERV\_classII} & 179048 & 21382713 &1.07 & 143640 & 16451857 & 0.83 &146189 &18906035 &0.94 &198036 &22430344 &1.03 \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{ \textbf{Class II}}\\[0.3ex]
 & \llap{DNA transposons:} & 259000 &53746062 & 2.68 & 261351 & 54598424 & 2.74 &264855 &55556571 &2.77 & 265748 &54859043 &2.53 \\
 & \llap{hAT-Charlie} &153463 & 28637685 & 1.43 & 154577 & 29132748 & 1.46 &156022 & 29603550 &1.47 & 156955 &29239810 &1.35 \\
 & \llap{TcMar-Tigger} &36981 & 11185164 & 0.56 & 38120 & 11441081 &0.57 &39444 &11766559 & 0.59 & 38989 &11514055 &0.53 \\
 &\llap{Rolling-circles} & 659955 & 72981412 &3.64 & 803681 & 84486255 & 4.24 &889437 &94191508 & 4.69 & 738026 &79989304 &3.68 \\
 & Unclassified. & 3128 & 509710 & 0.03 & 3147 & 512316 & 0.03 &3191 &518292 & 0.03 & 3167 &510872 &0.02 \\
\midrule
 & \textbf{Total} &0 & 00000 & 000.25 & 0 &712929637 & 35.78 & X & 00000 & 300
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear thank you so much,

Comment: what about if I want to add the grey highlight similar to LTR element to other class?

Comment: Yes, why not? I cloured this row specifically because in your code, it was framed, and I think it looks nicer with coloured background. You also can alternate colured background and no background: see the `\rowcolors` command defined in package `xcolor`.

Answer (score 3):

Some changes: first of all, `siunitx` for the numbers. Next I removed the first column, that takes space for nothing.

Then I reduced the font size and let TeX do the computations for the intercolumn spaces.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\caption{Summary of transposable elements }
\label{tab:Table1}

\footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule

Order &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{rom} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{act} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{erus} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{cos} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
& {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%}  & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Class I} \\
SINEs:               & 255687    & 30551159 & 1.52            & 257887  & 31080491  & 1.56             & 261248   &  31533761  & 1.57                    & 258371           & 30783770    &1.42 \\
Alu/B1               & 0 & 0     & 0.00                       & 0  & 0   & 0.00                        & 0       & 0      & 0.00                                       & 0       &0    & 0.00  \\
MIRs                 & 247894 & 30250569     & 1.51           & 249065  & 30760408   & 1.54            & 251376   & 31188301      & 1.55                 & 248923       &30437726    &1.40  \\
LINEs:               & 498627 & 207732214   & 10.37           & 501561  & 211005106  & 10.59           &516019  &220321176   &10.97                      & 543212      &226312996    &10.42  \\
LINE1               & 338909 & 163725095   & 8.17             & 342054  & 166954821   & 8.38           &354388  &175466399   &8.73                       &382755      &182566388     &8.40  \\
LINE2               & 133681  & 37311794    & 1.86            & 133693  & 37430629   &1.88             &135350   &38013575    &1.89                      &134657      &37312366      &1.72 \\
L3/CR1              & 16230   &3946140     & 0.20             & 16295   & 3952685  &0.20               &16386    &3999393     &0.20                      &16301         &3896521     &0.18 \\
RTE                 & 8327   & 2349410      & 0.12            & 8280   & 2342043   & 0.12              &8320    &2362314     &0.12                       &8391        &2315634     &0.11 \\
\midrule
LTR elements:        & 2368202 & 360743057   & 18.00         &2138613 & 331038087   & 16.61           &2043931   &305371407   &15.20                     &2399880      &376465663   &17.33 \\
\midrule
ERVL                 & 603471 & 94653879   & 4.72            & 535533 & 89635873  &4.50               &457960   &74681407   &3.72                        &589003      &95266242     &4.39 \\
ERVL-MaLRs            & 936686 & 137736037  & 6.87           & 757066 & 122605363  &6.15              &683557   &105114613   &5.23                       &927914      &138867517    &6.39 \\
ERV\_classI            & 401868 & 69495491  &3.47            & 476978 &72572164  &3.64                &458525   &72184510   &3.59                        &442380      &80571827     & 3.71\\
ERV\_classII           & 179048 & 21382713  &1.07            & 143640 & 16451857  & 0.83              &146189     &18906035   &0.94                      &198036        &22430344   &1.03 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Class II} \\
DNA transposons:    & 259000 &53746062  & 2.68             & 261351 & 54598424  & 2.74                     &264855  &55556571  &2.77                   & 265748      &54859043     &2.53 \\
\midrule
hAT-Charlie    &153463 & 28637685  & 1.43                 & 154577 & 29132748 & 1.46                      &156022  & 29603550  &1.47                   & 156955       &29239810    &1.35  \\
TcMar-Tigger    &36981 & 11185164  & 0.56                  & 38120 & 11441081 &0.57                      &39444   &11766559  &   0.59                  & 38989       &11514055   &0.53 \\
\midrule
Rolling-circles    & 659955 & 72981412  &3.64               & 803681 & 84486255 & 4.24                      &889437   &94191508  & 4.69                 & 738026       &79989304   &3.68 \\
\midrule
Unclassified.      & 3128 & 509710  & 0.03                 & 3147 & 512316 & 0.03                          &3191   &518292  & 0.03                     & 3167       &510872   &0.02  \\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Total} \\
& 0 & 0  & 0.00
& 0 & 0  & 0.00
& 0 & 0  & 0.00
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much dear, ppl up there in the comments they been testing my knowledge in latex, I though they are speaking Chinese

Comment: @BioInfo - Way to go! Bravo! Insult everyone, including all Chinese speakers. Keep it up, you'll go far.

Comment: Dear what if I want to add Whitespace before the subclass Example
SINEs:
      Alu/B1
      MIRs
LINEs:
       LINE1
And at the end the total numbers are nor align the numbers are down how can I make them all in one line, the total and number for Example:
Total  342 343 23.23%  234  3423  23.23% 234  3423  23.23%

Comment: @BioInfo Sorry, but I don't really understand. If you want some vertical space above “SINEs”, use ``\\[6pt]`` or similar to end the previous line. About the total, I can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Dear you have removed the figure i paste it only to explain my words

Comment: @BioInfo I removed nothing.

Comment: i have added your table to the question @egreg

Comment: @egreg kindly I added the figure to the question, will help in the matter of understanding, I would like to have whitespace before the subclass I highlighted it,