# How to add whitespace in LaTeX-table content

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, indentation

here is the table code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering

    \caption{Summary of transposable elements }
    \label{tab:Table1_SummaryTEs}

    \footnotesize

    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
      @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      l
      S[table-format=7.0]
      S[table-format=9.0]
      S[table-format=2.2]
      S[table-format=7.0]
      S[table-format=9.0]
      S[table-format=2.2]
      S[table-format=7.0]
      S[table-format=9.0]
      S[table-format=2.2]
      S[table-format=7.0]
      S[table-format=9.0]
      S[table-format=2.2]
    }
    \toprule

    Order &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{rom} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{act} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{rs} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{vos} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
    & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%}  & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%} \\
    \midrule

    \multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Class I} \\
    SINEs:               & 255687    & 30551159 & 1.52            & 257887  & 31080491  & 1.56             & 261248   &  31533761  & 1.57                    & 258371           & 30783770    &1.42 \\
    Alu/B1              & 0 & 0     & 0.00          & 0  & 0   & 0.00                        & 0       & 0      & 0.00                         & 0                &0            & 0.00  \\
        MIRs                 & 247894 & 30250569     & 1.51           & 249065  & 30760408   & 1.54            & 251376   & 31188301      & 1.55                 & 248923       &30437726         &1.40  \\
    LINEs:               & 498628 & 207732214   & 10.37           & 501561  & 211005106  & 10.59           &516019    &220321176   &10.97                      & 543212      &226312996         &10.42  \\
        LINE1               & 338909 & 163725095   & 8.17             & 342054  & 166954821   & 8.38           &354388    &175466399   &8.73                       &382755      &182566388          &8.40  \\
    LINE2               & 133681  & 37311794    & 1.86            & 133693  & 37430629   &1.88             &135350    &38013575    &1.89                      &134657      &37312366         &1.72 \\
    L3/CR1              & 16230   &3946140     & 0.20             & 16295   & 3952685  &0.20               &16386    &3999393     &0.20                      &16301         &3896521         &0.18 \\
    RTE                 & 8327   & 2349410      & 0.12            & 8280   & 2342043   & 0.12              &8320    &2362314     &0.12                       &8391        &2315634      &0.11 \\

    LTR elements:        & 2368202 & 360743057   & 18.00         &2138613 & 331038087   & 16.61           &2043931   &305371407   &15.20                     &2399880      &376465663   &17.33 \\
    ERVL                 & 603471 & 94653879   & 4.72            & 535533 & 89635873  &4.50               &457960   &74681407   &3.72                        &589003      &95266242     &4.39 \\
    ERVL-MaLRs            & 936686 & 137736037  & 6.87           & 757066 & 122605363  &6.15              &683557   &105114613   &5.23                       &927914      &138867517    &6.39 \\
    ERV\_classI            & 401868 & 69495491  &3.47            & 476978 &72572164  &3.64                &458525   &72184510   &3.59                        &442380      &80571827     & 3.71\\
    ERV\_classII           & 179048 & 21382713  &1.07            & 143640 & 16451857  & 0.83              &146189     &18906035   &0.94                      &198036        &22430344   &1.03 \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

    \multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Class II} \\
    DNA transposons:    & 259000 &53746062  & 2.68             & 261351 & 54598424  & 2.74                     &264855  &55556571  &2.77                   & 265748      &54859043     &2.53 \\
    hAT-Charlie    &153463 & 28637685  & 1.43                 & 154577 & 29132748 & 1.46                      &156022  & 29603550  &1.47                   & 156955       &29239810    &1.35  \\
    TcMar-Tigger    &36981 & 11185164  & 0.56                  & 38120 & 11441081 &0.57                      &39444   &11766559  &   0.59                  & 38989       &11514055   &0.53 \\
    Rolling-circles    & 659955 & 72981412  &3.64               & 803681 & 84486255 & 4.24                      &889437   &94191508  & 4.69                 & 738026       &79989304   &3.68 \\
    \midrule
    Unclassified.      & 3128 & 509710  & 0.03                 & 3147 & 512316 & 0.03                          &3191   &518292  & 0.03                     & 3167       &510872   &0.02  \\

    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    Total & 7101158& 726470712  & 36.25
    & 6821541 & 712929637  & 35.78
    & 6686198 & 707734238  & 35.22
    & 7352708 & 769117479  & 35.41
    \end{tabular*}

    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add whitespace before the subclasses highlighted in the picture below
[image]

the expected output should look like: the subgroups have whitespace before
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your MWE to be compilable?

Comment: See @Bernard answer on your previus question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532495/help-my-ugly-latex-table

Comment: on the previous question, no answer provided @Zarko . what do you mean

Comment: @TimHilt what do you mean?

Comment: @BioInfo, on answer mentioned on my comment, you receive two answers, one from egreg, one from Bernard. Check again, please. Also check your question. Ttile of question is in contradiction with red note on showed table.

Comment: @BioInfo if i copy your code in an editor i should be able to compile the file with pdflatex or something alike.

Comment: @TimHilt kindly check the question again if this is fulfil your request

Comment: @BioInfo yes, that's better. Thank you. However i would suggest you to to follow Zarkos comment before anyone posts an answer here.

Comment: @Vincent Unfortunately no